# Binaries are added to project when NuGet package has Grpc.Core as a dependency

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, grpc

I'm encountering an interesting issue and it could be something I don't know about NuGet currently, but I am creating a NuGet package, which I'll call *Project Alpha*, that has a dependency on `Grpc`, which, in extension, has a dependency on the problematic package: `Grpc.Core`.

`Grpc.Core`, via `Grpc` installs fine in *Project Alpha* and adds no new files to *Project Alpha*'s project. *Project Beta*, on the other hand, depends upon *Project Alpha*, and in extension `Grpc.Core`. When I install *Project Alpha*, the installation of `Grpc.Core` causes the following project tree in *Project Beta*

```
ProjectBeta
|- Properties/
|- References/
|- App.config
|- grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll
|- grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.dylib
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.dylib
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so
|- packages.config
|- Program.cs
```

You'll notice that it installs 6 binary files that I do not want 1) included in the project or 2) at the project root.

After looking at the `Grpc.Core.nupkg`, I found that the 6 binary files came from a `runtimes` folder; however, only a `.targets` file referenced them and explicitly said to copy to the output directory. It should be noted that it will build correctly by copying those files to the output directory.

For more reference:

Project Alpha Dependency Tree

```
Project Alpha
|- Grpc
|  |- Grpc.Core
|- Google.Protobuf
```

results in the following nupkg after running `nuget pack ProjectAlpha.csproj -Properties Configuration=Release`

```
content
|- grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll
|- grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.dylib
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.dylib
|- libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so
lib
|- net452
   |- ProjectAlpha.dll
```

Ultimately, it seems like I need to figure out what to do with those binary files so that they no longer get packaged as `content` files, but I am not sure what is causing this problem in the first place. Ideally, I'd like to have a solution that isn't just "Why don't you just delete the files since it builds?". If that ends up being the only solution, then I will do that; however, I don't think that is a real solution.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Hacks?

Comment: Why is there a .targets file? What is the purpose; only copying the files? You should create 2 packages; one for x64 and one for x86.

Comment: It's not my package. I do not have the `.targets` file in my package; it is found in `Grpc.Core`, which I have no control over. The purpose of the `.targets` file seems to be to copy the appropriate binary to the output directory. I don't think the x86 vs x64 concern you have has any relevance.

Comment: Here is a snippet from the actual `.targets` file in case this matters to someone ```<Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\runtimes\win\native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll</Link>
    </Content>```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I had attempted to use `.nuspec` and exclude the binaries, but that did not work and I actually received problems just installing the NuGet package.

The best approach I found (because it works for me) is to use the command-line arguments for `nuget pack` that I missed before, which is `-Exclude`.

So the final command I used to package up the `.csproj` is

```
nuget pack ProjectAlpha.csproj -Exclude **\*.x86.*;**\*.x64.*
```

In case the solution is not clear, `nuget pack` will package up everything found in the output directory (`bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`) and the problem was arising because there were 6 binaries for which NuGet didn't know the origin. I know they were copied via the `.targets` file in `Grpc.Core`'s NuGet package. So, they needed to be excluded because the `.targets` file would copy them correctly in any subsequent project that would include `Grpc.Core`. Thus, `-Exclude` worked.

I still do not know why it worked better in this case than a `.nuspec` exclude attribute, but I'm happy that it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue when packing a .csproj file which installed Grpc.Core package directly. Then I check the .nuspec file, I don't find  node which will lead to the content files add into consume project.

So I create a .nuspec file for my nuget package project and then modify the .nuspec file as following, which only contains the package basic information and the dependencies information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>MyPackage</title>
    <authors>My Name</authors>
    <owners>My Name</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ?  2017</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Grpc.Core" version="1.0.1" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
```

Then I pack this .nuspec file to .nupkg file and install this package in another project. It doesn't add that 6 binary files into my project any more.

Comment: I specifically want to pack the `.csproj` file because I don't want to maintain the listing of included files in the `.csproj` and the `.nuspec`. If it is not possible to do that, then this is probably what I'll have to resort to, then.

Comment: Do you know why there would be the difference between packaging methods of the `.csproj` vs `.nuspec`?

Comment: When packing .csproj, it will pack all project dependencies files automatically, no matter the files will be used or not. And the .nuspec file could help us add the files that we needed into the package, which more definitely.

Comment: I tried using the `.nuspec` approach and get an error when I install the package: `Failed to add reference to 'grpc_csharp_ext.x64'`. The 2 dependencies I have are `Grpc@1.0.1` and `Google.Protobuf@3.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem myself, and struggled to find a satisfactory solution.

I wanted to try to keep the package generation inside the `csproj` file as much as possible, but skip including the native libraries from the package.

What did the trick for me was setting additional options for the `PackageReference` tag, like so:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="2.33.1">
  <IncludeAssets>compile; build</IncludeAssets>
  <ExcludeAssets>runtime; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Basically, we want to keep the `compile` and `build` assets, because they will allow the project to compile, but we want to exclude everything else (especially `runtime` and `native`, which are the major offenders in the package).

This produced a ~100KB `.nupkg` file instead of ~135MB, while preserving the dependency upon the `Grpc.Core` package.

Win!